# Queued Background tasks - How to queue up and run multiple jobs simultaneously - IBackgroundTaskQueue

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to queue and run multiple jobs in a background service, simultaneously.
I have a Job object that will poll various FTP sites, download files etc. I'd like to load all my Jobs and run them in parallel.  I believe I can use **IHostedServer** and **IBackgroundTaskQueue**.  Like this
[ASP .Net Core Queued background tasks parallel processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867167/asp-net-core-queued-background-tasks-parallel-processing)

How do I queue my Jobs up and run them?    Something like this?  **Is this the correct approach?**  Loop thru my collection of jobs and 'execute'? A workitem?

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {      
       foreach (var job in Jobs)
        {
            var executorTask = new Task(
                async () =>
                {
              ???
```

Comment: Never ever create a Task by calling its constructor. Please prefer Task.Run

Comment: Could you please share with us the definition of Jobs?

Comment: Job iis file watcher class